# How to add virtual attributes to API json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

**Context**: ruby "2.0.0" and rails "4.0.0"

I am wondering how to return more data than a simple JSON representation of my model. I have this method in my API controller:

```
def show
  @entry = params[:id].to_i != 0 ? Entry.find(params[:id]) : Entry.where(slug: params[:id]).first
  respond_with @entry
end
```

which returns a well formatted JSON article when called via `http://pow.url.dev/en/tenant/api/v1/entries/23`.

I also have two other method to get the next and previous article, for instance, `next` looks like this:

```
def next
  @current_entry = params[:entry_id].to_i != 0 ? Entry.find(params[:entry_id]) : Entry.where(slug: params[:entry_id]).first
  @entry = Entry.where( status_id: 0 ).where( "published_at > ?", @current_entry.published_at ).first
  respond_with @entry
end
```

The problem is that the client application needs to make 3 API calls to *1) fetch an article, 2) fetch the next article and 3) fetch the previous article.*

It would be much better if the client had to do only one call to get all the information at once.

I would like to add into the `show` method the **Title and ID** of the next and previous article along with the JSON result, what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
def show
  @entry = ...
  render :json => @entry.attributes.merge({
    :next_id => id_of_next_article, 
    :next_title => title_of_next_article...
  })
end
```

More flexible solution: use some sort of JSON serialization customizers (or roll your own), one I've used before is ActiveModel Serializers (https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). I'm sure there are others.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Unlike `respond_with`, `render :json` does not render the association active records without specifying them using the `:include` option. How can I add these associations AR to the response?

Comment: Yeah my quick and dirty solution won't do that, have a look at the documentation for the built in to_json function. You can include the output of instance methods on the model, so you could implement the next_id and next_title methods and include that in the outputted JSON

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Just accepted your answer and posted my own answer in case it could help anyone. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Will the user always use the Next and the Prev articles? If so, put them together on the JSON, otherwise, use link location tags with REL to `prev` and `next` on the returning JSON, then the clint will be able to know where to get the `next` and `prev` articles. You can get more info: [RESTful Web Service usage of custom link relations - 'rel'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026275/restful-web-service-usage-of-custom-link-relations-rel)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I cannot rewrite the entire API to be HAL-compliant. I will definitely look into this later on though.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution I came up with:**

Implementing two methods in the Entry model object for `next` and `previous` as follows:

```
def next
  Entry.where( status_id: 0 ).where( "published_at > ?", self.published_at ).select('id, title, slug').first
end

def previous
  Entry.where( status_id: 0 ).where( "published_at < ?", self.published_at ).select('id, title, slug').last
end
```

and replace `respond_with` by `render :json` in the `show` action of my controller:

```
def show
  @entry = params[:id].to_i != 0 ? Entry.find(params[:id]) : Entry.where(slug: params[:id]).first
  render :json => @entry.to_json(:include => :entry_fields, 
                                 :methods => [:next, :previous])
end
```

Output:

```
{
    "id": 20,
    "title": "Video Test",
    "slug": "video-test",
    "status_id": 0,
    "promoted": true,
    "published_at": "2014-01-20T11:51:00.000Z",
    "created_at": "2014-01-20T11:51:37.406Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-03-05T13:42:49.981Z",
    "excerpt": "Video",
    "user_id": "933dc175-0d73-45fb-9437-61ecc4f55705",
    "next": {
        "id": 21,
        "title": "Test Multiple",
        "slug": "test-multiple"
    },
    "previous": {
        "id": 18,
        "title": "Example Entry",
        "slug": "example-entry"
    },
    ...
    ... (associations)
    ...
}
```